# The difference between "" vs " " Javascript

Tags: javascript

I used this to remove white spaces from a string.

```
returnString.split(" ").filter(substr => substr !== "");
```

In my head it should be this:

```
returnString.split(" ").filter(substr => substr !== " ")    //note the space between the " "
```

why doesnt the bottom one work? Is it JS sytax?

Answer: If theres a space at the beginning of the string, its split with an empty string, (so substr !== "")  removes that from the returned array when splitting the string.

Comment: When you split on spaces, you won't have spaces in your array.

Comment: Consider the case where you have multiple delimiters: `"hello   there  ".split(" ")` which gives you `[ 'hello', '', '', 'there', '', '' ]`

Comment: I think `returnString.split("").filter(substr => substr !== " ");` is what you think you're doing.

Comment: if theres a space at the beginning of the string, it'll add that to the array       " The dogs fur"   will return [" ", "The", "dogs", "fur"]

Answer (score -1):

`returnString.replace(/\s/g,'')` Would be a superior way of doing this.

`""` is an empty string.

`" "` is a space character.

They cannot be used interchangeably.

Answer (score -1):

`""` is an empty string.

If there is a space at the beginning of the string, it will split that space with an empty string.

that is why `substr !== ""` is needed to remove the empty string.

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned in the comments, you’re splitting on whitespaces, creating indices for said whitespaces in an array.

```
const returnString = 'Hello I am Victor'

const str = returnString.split("").filter(substr => substr !== " ");

console.log(str.join(''))
```

would get you the desired result.

However, a regex pattern would be best suited for this use case.

```
returnString.replace(/\s/g, '')
```